# exclude is ignored in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have 2 Typescript projects nested in each other.

```
> App 1
  => src
  => node_modules
  tsconfig.json
  => App2
    => src
    => node_modules
    tsconfig.json
```

When I try compiling `App2`, typescript tries to compile `../../node_modules`, but I have "node_modules" in my exclude setting. How can I stop it from reading those `node_modules` ?

```json
{
  "include": ["blah-webapp/src/**/*.*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "server", "electron", "src/sw.js"]
}
```

I also tried adding `"../../node_modules/"` specifically. I run `yarn tsc` inside of `App 1/App2`

[image: ../node_modules]

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question earlier today? What happened to the earlier version?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, I did not ...

Comment: Same exact title. That seems....surprising.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you provided a solution on the last post that was similar could you post it here again ? I cannot find another question with the same name

Comment: Sorry, I didn't, I'd have voted duplicate if I had. I've never had to debug an `excludes` problem. Good luck, I hope you find the problem soon!